# Control for input in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a windows-application in c#.net 2010. It is basically an Inventory Management Application. Here user will make Invoices.

The problem is that their can be `n` numbers of items in an invoice. how can i take input from user from `n` numbers of item?

In VB6.0 i was using mshflex grid with text box and different controls integrated it mshflexgrid as per need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use editable `DataGridView`. Instead of filling Invoice Forms users can directly keyin the details into GridView rows. Which will allow the users to insert any number of invoice details.

**EDIT**

To Open a window next to the cell currently focused.

You could use `CellEnter` event which gets fired when a `Cell` gets focus on a DatGridView.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
       //Give the relevant column index where pop up windows needs to be opened.
    if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(1))
    {
        //Getting the position of the current cell.
        Point loc = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an option but in my case there are certain columns in which user have to select values he cant enter any thing. Like in VB i used listbox control. as soon as mshflexgrid focus reach to the desired column a list box gets open just near the current cell and user focus is moved to the listbox, now he can select the value from listbox and by pressing enter key the value gets copied to the current cell and listbox gets invisible. And the user focus is moved to the next column. can I perform this type of task in datagridview in c#?Plz guide me if can b possible.

Comment: @DIPS, if an answer helped you, please mark it as "Answered" so other people with the same problem as you, know how you solved it. If you have additional questions, either expand your original question, or consider posting a new question.

Comment: @AccessDenied Sir can you please tell me how I can do this. I mean displaying any control on getting focus to desired column. and I also want to move through the rows and columns using enter key in datagrid. I am very new to programming so plz dont mind if I m asking you for little detail.

Comment: @DIPS I have updated the answer. It will give you an idea of how to approach this problem. You can create a small form with ComboBox or List box as you need and you can open that window when focus is on the specific column(cell) using the sample code i have posted. Then you can easly pass the selected valeu form Pop up window to the current cell in the DataGridView.

Comment: @AccessDenied Yes I am going to try this.. and I understood what you were trying to explain. This will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView. You can enter data into each cell as follows:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value;
```

A new row can be inserted by simply putting this code:

```
 this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

There is an alternative way. You can create a form for storing information of a single item with text boxes, combo-box, labels, buttons etc. After entering the data for an item, using a button you can save the data. Then clear all controls. Now, enter the information of next item and so on.

Comment: Thanks for help.Please see my comment on previous answer. I want something like that.

Comment: You can use a ComboBox inside a DataGridView. There are many posts in Stack OverFlow that explains this.